# Prevent flushing the buffer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5, rtmpd

How can I prevent the flushing of the buffer until the playing is finished in AS3?

Is it possible?

The buffer is emptied and flushed 10-11 seconds before the real end of the flv file.

The file is locally saved and I stream it though crtmp server.

I cannot seek the last 10 seconds because of empty buffer. How can I stop flash from flushing the buffer at end?

Comment: I think you can't stop buffer from flushing data. Instead why don't you add up the whole data together and only after that start to write the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you create your own flash based player, I think you should use the proper signal handlers to signal end-of-stream.

Also, I'm not experiencing that problem. Just to test it, use JWPlayer or FlowPlayer and see if you can seek around. On my side, everything works as expected

Comment: Yes but buffer gets emptied i.e I get "Done streaming file" message in my streaming server log. So I cannot seek empty buffer. What do you think, this is a server issue?